Todo list manager
I've completed a roadmap.sh project: https://roadmap.sh/projects/task-tracker/
It's my first rust project. So there's probably a lot of things that could be done in a more idiomatic way.
It's a CLI tool to manage a todo list save in a JSON file.
Example

Adding a new task
task-cli add "Buy groceries"

Updating and deleting tasks
task-cli update 1 "Buy groceries and cook dinner"
task-cli delete 1

Marking a task as in progress or done
task-cli mark-in-progress 1
task-cli mark-done 1

Listing all tasks
task-cli list

Listing tasks by status
task-cli list done
task-cli list todo
task-cli list in-progress


The full code can be found on github if you prefer for readability
Cargo.toml
[package]
name = "taskTracker"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
build = "build.rs"


[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1.0.213", features = ["derive"] }
serde_json = "1.0.132"
tempfile = "3.13.0"
chrono = { version = "0.4", features = ["serde"] }

Main.rs
use crate::task_repository::Task;
use crate::task_repository::TaskRepository;
use crate::task_repository::TaskStatus;
use std::env;
use std::process::ExitCode;
use std::string::ToString;

pub mod task_repository;

/// The main entry point of the application.
///
/// This function reads command-line arguments and the `TASK_FILE` environment variable,
/// loads the task repository, and handles the provided command.
///
/// # Returns
///
/// An `ExitCode` indicating the success or failure of the operation.
fn main() -> ExitCode {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    if args.len() < 2 {
        println!("No command provided, goodbye.");
        return ExitCode::from(0);
    }

    let task_file = match env::var("TASK_FILE") {
        Ok(val) => val,
        Err(_) => {
            println!("TASK_FILE environment variable not set");
            return ExitCode::from(1);
        }
    };

    println!("Reading tasks from {}", task_file);
    let mut repo = task_repository::load_repository(&task_file);

    match handle_command(&args, &mut repo) {
        Ok(_) => ExitCode::from(0),
        Err(err) => {
            println!("{}", err);
            ExitCode::from(1)
        }
    }
}

/// Handles the provided command by delegating to the appropriate function.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `args` - A slice of command-line arguments.
/// * `repo` - A mutable reference to the `TaskRepository`.
///
/// # Returns
///
/// A `Result` indicating the success or failure of the operation.
fn handle_command(args: &[String], repo: &mut TaskRepository) -> Result<(), String> {
    let param1 = &args[1];
    match param1.as_str() {
        "list" => handle_list_command(args, repo),
        "add" => handle_add_command(args, repo),
        "delete" => handle_delete_command(args, repo),
        "update" => handle_update_command(args, repo),
        "mark-in-progress" => handle_mark_in_progress_command(args, repo),
        _ => Err(format!("Unknown parameter {}", param1)),
    }
}

/// Handles the "list" command to display tasks.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `args` - A slice of command-line arguments.
/// * `repo` - A reference to the `TaskRepository`.
///
/// # Returns
///
/// A `Result` indicating the success or failure of the operation.
fn handle_list_command(args: &[String], repo: &TaskRepository) -> Result<(), String> {
    if args.len() == 2 {
        print_tasks(repo);
    } else if args.len() == 3 {
        match args[2].as_str() {
            "todo" => print_tasks_by_status(repo, TaskStatus::Todo),
            "done" => print_tasks_by_status(repo, TaskStatus::Done),
            "in-progress" => print_tasks_by_status(repo, TaskStatus::InProgress),
            _ => return Err("Unknown status to display".to_string()),
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}

/// Handles the "add" command to add a new task.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `args` - A slice of command-line arguments.
/// * `repo` - A mutable reference to the `TaskRepository`.
///
/// # Returns
///
/// A `Result` indicating the success or failure of the operation.
fn handle_add_command(args: &[String], repo: &mut TaskRepository) -> Result<(), String> {
    if args.len() < 3 {
        return Err("Missing description to add a new task".to_string());
    }
    add_task(repo, args[2].clone());
    Ok(())
}

/// Handles the "delete" command to delete a task.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `args` - A slice of command-line arguments.
/// * `repo` - A mutable reference to the `TaskRepository`.
///
/// # Returns
///
/// A `Result` indicating the success or failure of the operation.
fn handle_delete_command(args: &[String], repo: &mut TaskRepository) -> Result<(), String> {
    if args.len() < 3 {
        return Err("Missing id of task to delete".to_string());
    }
    delete_task(repo, args[2].clone().parse::<i32>().unwrap());
    Ok(())
}

/// Handles the "update" command to update a task's description.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `args` - A slice of command-line arguments.
/// * `repo` - A mutable reference to the `TaskRepository`.
///
/// # Returns
///
/// A `Result` indicating the success or failure of the operation.
fn handle_update_command(args: &[String], repo: &mut TaskRepository) -> Result<(), String> {
    if args.len() < 4 {
        return Err("Missing update parameters".to_string());
    }
    update_task(
        repo,
        args[2].clone().parse::<i32>().unwrap(),
        args[3].clone(),
    );
    Ok(())
}

/// Handles the "mark-in-progress" command to mark a task as in progress.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `args` - A slice of command-line arguments.
/// * `repo` - A mutable reference to the `TaskRepository`.
///
/// # Returns
///
fn handle_mark_in_progress_command(
    args: &[String],
    repo: &mut TaskRepository,
) -> Result<(), String> {
    if args.len() < 3 {
        return Err("Missing id of task to progress".to_string());
    }
    mark_in_progress(repo, args[2].clone().parse::<i32>().unwrap());
    Ok(())
}

/// Prints tasks filtered by their status.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `repo` - A reference to the `TaskRepository`.
/// * `status` - The `TaskStatus` to filter tasks by.
fn print_tasks_by_status(repo: &TaskRepository, status: TaskStatus) {
    let task_list: Vec<_> = repo.tasks().filter(|task| task.status == status).collect();
    if task_list.is_empty() {
        println!("No task with status {}", status);
    } else {
        task_list.into_iter().for_each(print_task);
    }
}

/// Prints all tasks in the repository.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `repository` - A reference to the `TaskRepository`.
fn print_tasks(repository: &TaskRepository) {
    if repository.task_count() > 0 {
        repository.tasks().for_each(print_task);
    } else {
        println!("Your task list is empty.");
    }
}

/// Prints a single task.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `task` - A reference to the `Task` to be printed.
fn print_task(task: &Task) {
    println!(
        "Task {}: \"{}\" {}. Created at: {}. Last update: {}",
        task.id, task.description, task.status, task.created_at, task.created_at
    );
}

/// Adds a new task to the repository.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `repo` - A mutable reference to the `TaskRepository`.
/// * `desc` - A string describing the new task.
fn add_task(repo: &mut TaskRepository, desc: String) {
    repo.new_task(desc);
    save_repository(repo);
}

/// Deletes a task from the repository.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `repo` - A mutable reference to the `TaskRepository`.
/// * `task_id` - The ID of the task to be deleted.
///
/// # Returns
///
/// An `Option` containing the deleted `Task` if it existed.
fn delete_task(repo: &mut TaskRepository, task_id: i32) -> Option<Task> {
    let ret = repo.delete(task_id);
    save_repository(repo);
    ret
}

/// Updates the description of a task.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `repo` - A mutable reference to the `TaskRepository`.
/// * `id` - The ID of the task to be updated.
/// * `new_desc` - The new description for the task.
fn update_task(repo: &mut TaskRepository, id: i32, new_desc: String) {
    let task = repo.task(id);
    task.description = new_desc;
    save_repository(repo);
}

/// Saves the current state of the task repository to the file specified by the `TASK_FILE` environment variable.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `repo` - A mutable reference to the `TaskRepository`.
fn save_repository(repo: &mut TaskRepository) {
    println!("Saving tasks to {}", task_file_name());
    task_repository::save_repository(repo, &task_file_name());
}

/// Computes the name of the file to store tasks in.
/// The name is read from the `TASK_FILE` environment variable, or defaults to "tasks_file.txt".
fn task_file_name() -> String {
    env::var("TASK_FILE").unwrap_or("tasks_file.txt".to_string())
}

/// Marks a task as in progress.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `repo` - A mutable reference to the `TaskRepository`.
/// * `id` - The ID of the task to be marked as in progress.
fn mark_in_progress(repo: &mut TaskRepository, id: i32) {
    repo.task(id).status = TaskStatus::InProgress;
    save_repository(repo);
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use std::path::Path;
    use tempfile::{Builder, TempDir};

    fn setup() {
        let tmp_dir = Builder::new()
            .prefix("task_list_test")
            .rand_bytes(10)
            .keep(true)
            .tempdir()
            .unwrap();
        let _ = env::set_current_dir(&tmp_dir);
    }
    #[test]
    fn task_added() {
        setup();
        let mut repo = TaskRepository::default();
        add_task(&mut repo, "TestTask".to_string());
        let task = &repo.task(1);
        assert_eq!(task.description, "TestTask");
        assert_eq!(task.id, 1);
    }

    #[test]
    fn task_id_incremental() {
        setup();
        let mut repo = TaskRepository::default();
        repo.new_task(String::from("TestTask"));
        repo.new_task(String::from("otherTask"));
        let task2 = &repo.task(2);
        assert_eq!(task2.description, "otherTask");
        assert_eq!(task2.id, 2);
    }

    #[test]
    fn list_task() {
        setup();
        let mut repo = TaskRepository::default();
        repo.new_task(String::from("TestTask"));
        repo.new_task(String::from("otherTask"));
        assert_eq!(repo.task_count(), 2);
    }

    #[test]
    fn delete_task() {
        setup();
        let mut repo = TaskRepository::default();
        repo.new_task("Plop".to_string());
        repo.new_task("Plip".to_strenter code hereing());
        repo.delete(1);
        assert_eq!(repo.task_count(), 1);
        let task = repo.task(2);
        assert_eq!(task.id, 2);
        assert_eq!(task.description, String::from("Plip"));
        assert_eq!(task.status, TaskStatus::Todo);
    }

    #[test]
    fn update_task_with_desc_by_id() {
        setup();
        let mut repo = TaskRepository::default();
        repo.new_task("Plop".to_string());
        repo.new_task("Plip".to_string());
        update_task(&mut repo, 2, "New desc".to_string());
        assert_eq!(repo.task(2).description, "New desc");
    }

    #[test]
    fn update_inprogress() {
        setup();
        let mut repo = TaskRepository::default();
        repo.new_task("Plop".to_string());
        mark_in_progress(&mut repo, 1);
        assert_eq!(repo.task(1).status, TaskStatus::InProgress);
    }

    #[test]
    fn save_load_repo() {
        setup();
        let mut repo = TaskRepository::default();
        repo.new_task("Plop".to_string());
        repo.new_task("Plip".to_string());
        mark_in_progress(&mut repo, 1);
        let tmp_dir = TempDir::new().unwrap();
        let tmp_file = tmp_dir.path().join(Path::new("tmp_file.txt"));
        task_repository::save_repository(&mut repo, &tmp_file);
        let loaded_repo = task_repository::load_repository(&tmp_file);
        assert_eq!(repo, loaded_repo);
    }
}

task_repository.rs
use chrono::{DateTime, Local};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::collections::hash_map::Values;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::fmt::{Display, Formatter};
use std::fs;
use std::fs::OpenOptions;
use std::io::{BufReader, Write};
use std::path::Path;

/// Represents the status of a task.
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum TaskStatus {
    Todo,
    InProgress,
    Done,
}

/// Represents a task with an ID, description, status, and timestamps.
#[derive(PartialEq, Debug, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Task {
    pub id: i32,
    pub description: String,
    pub status: TaskStatus,
    pub created_at: DateTime<Local>,
    pub updated_at: DateTime<Local>,
}

/// A repository for managing tasks, including a map of tasks and the last assigned ID.
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug, Default)]
pub struct TaskRepository {
    tasks: HashMap<i32, Task>,
    last_id: i32,
}

impl Display for TaskStatus {
    /// Formats the `TaskStatus` for display.
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match *self {
            TaskStatus::Todo => write!(f, "Todo"),
            TaskStatus::InProgress => write!(f, "In Progress"),
            TaskStatus::Done => write!(f, "Done"),
        }
    }
}

/// A struct used for serializing and deserializing `TaskRepository`
/// In `TaskRepository` `Task`s objects are stored in a hashmap
/// Serializing a hash map in json produce a map <id,task>
/// Since each task already hold its id we prefere to store vec instead
/// The json produced is lighter and more readable
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct TaskRepositoryForSerialization {
    tasks: Vec<Task>,
}

impl TaskRepository {
    /// Creates a `TaskRepository` from a `TaskRepositoryForSerialization` object.
    ///
    /// # Arguments
    ///
    /// * `object` - A `TaskRepositoryForSerialization` object.
    ///
    /// # Returns
    ///
    /// A `TaskRepository` instance.
    fn from_serialization(object: TaskRepositoryForSerialization) -> Self {
        let mut task_repository = TaskRepository::default();
        let mut max_id = 0;
        for task in object.tasks {
            if task.id > max_id {
                max_id = task.id
            }
            task_repository.tasks.insert(task.id, task);
        }
        task_repository.last_id = max_id;
        task_repository
    }

    /// Adds a new task with the given description to the repository.
    ///
    /// # Arguments
    ///
    /// * `description` - A string describing the task.
    pub fn new_task(&mut self, description: String) {
        self.last_id += 1;
        let task = Task {
            description,
            id: self.last_id,
            status: TaskStatus::Todo,
            created_at: Local::now(),
            updated_at: Local::now(),
        };
        self.tasks.insert(self.last_id, task);
    }

    /// Converts the `TaskRepository` into a `TaskRepositoryForSerialization` object.
    ///
    /// # Returns
    ///
    /// A `TaskRepositoryForSerialization` object.
    fn serializable(&self) -> TaskRepositoryForSerialization {
        let mut vec: Vec<Task> = self.tasks.values().cloned().collect();
        vec.sort_by(|a, b| a.id.cmp(&b.id));
        TaskRepositoryForSerialization { tasks: vec }
    }

    /// Deletes a task with the given ID from the repository.
    ///
    /// # Arguments
    ///
    /// * `id` - The ID of the task to delete.
    ///
    /// # Returns
    ///
    /// An `Option` containing the deleted task if it existed.
    pub fn delete(&mut self, id: i32) -> Option<Task> {
        self.tasks.remove(&id)
    }

    /// Returns an iterator over the tasks in the repository.
    ///
    /// # Returns
    ///
    /// An iterator over the tasks.
    pub fn tasks(&self) -> Values<'_, i32, Task> {
        self.tasks.values()
    }

    /// Returns a mutable reference to the task with the given ID.
    ///
    /// # Arguments
    ///
    /// * `id` - The ID of the task to retrieve.
    ///
    /// # Returns
    ///
    /// A mutable reference to the task.
    pub fn task(&mut self, id: i32) -> &mut Task {
        self.tasks.get_mut(&id).unwrap()
    }

    /// Returns the number of tasks in the repository.
    ///
    /// # Returns
    ///
    /// The number of tasks.
    pub fn task_count(&self) -> usize {
        self.tasks.len()
    }
}

/// Load a `TaskRepository` from a JSON file at the provided path.
///
/// If the file does not exist, a default `TaskRepository` is returned.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `file_path` - A reference to a path that implements the `AsRef<Path>` trait.
///
/// # Returns
///
/// A `TaskRepository` loaded from the JSON file.
pub fn load_repository(file_path: &impl AsRef<Path>) -> TaskRepository {
    if !fs::exists(file_path).unwrap() {
        return TaskRepository::default();
    }
    let file = OpenOptions::new()
        .read(true)
        .create(true)
        .truncate(false)
        .write(true)
        .open(file_path)
        .unwrap();
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let repo_object: TaskRepositoryForSerialization = serde_json::from_reader(reader).unwrap();
    TaskRepository::from_serialization(repo_object)
}

/// Save a `TaskRepository` to a JSON file at the provided path.
///
/// # Arguments
///
/// * `repo` - A mutable reference to the `TaskRepository` to be saved.
/// * `file_path` - A reference to a path that implements the `AsRef<Path>` trait.
pub fn save_repository(repo: &mut TaskRepository, file_path: &impl AsRef<Path>) {
    let mut list_file = fs::File::create(file_path).unwrap();
    let _ = list_file.write(
        serde_json::to_string(&repo.serializable())
            .unwrap()
            .as_bytes(),
    );
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    use chrono::TimeZone;
    use serde_json::Value;

    #[test]
    fn repository_save_json() {
        let mut repo = TaskRepository::default();
        repo.new_task(String::from("plop"));
        repo.new_task(String::from("plap"));
        repo.task(1).status = TaskStatus::Done;
        let serialized_data = serde_json::to_string(&repo.serializable()).unwrap();
        let json_object: Value = serde_json::from_str(&serialized_data).unwrap();

        assert_eq!(json_object["tasks"][0]["description"], "plop");
        assert_eq!(json_object["tasks"][0]["status"], "Done");
        assert_eq!(json_object["tasks"][1]["description"], "plap");
    }

    #[test]
    fn repository_load_json() {
        let expected = HashMap::from([
            (
                0,
                Task {
                    id: 0,
                    description: String::from("plop"),
                    status: TaskStatus::Todo,
                    created_at: DateTime::from(
                        Local.with_ymd_and_hms(2024, 01, 01, 01, 02, 03).unwrap(),
                    ),
                    updated_at: DateTime::from(
                        Local.with_ymd_and_hms(2024, 02, 01, 05, 02, 03).unwrap(),
                    ),
                },
            ),
            (
                1,
                Task {
                    id: 1,
                    description: String::from("plap"),
                    status: TaskStatus::Done,
                    created_at: DateTime::from(
                        Local.with_ymd_and_hms(2024, 03, 06, 01, 02, 03).unwrap(),
                    ),
                    updated_at: DateTime::from(
                        Local.with_ymd_and_hms(2024, 02, 01, 05, 12, 03).unwrap(),
                    ),
                },
            ),
        ]);
        let content = format!(
            "\
        {{\
        \"tasks\": [\
            {{\
                \"id\": 0,\
                \"description\": \"plop\",\
                \"status\": \"Todo\",\
                \"created_at\":\"2024-10-16T14:45:18.529270461+02:00\",\
                \"updated_at\":\"2024-10-16T14:45:18.529569668+02:00\"
            }},\
            {{\
                \"id\": 1,\
                \"description\": \"plap\",\
                \"status\": \"Done\",\
                \"created_at\":\"2024-10-16T14:45:18.529270461+02:00\",\
                \"updated_at\":\"2024-10-16T14:45:18.529569668+02:00\"
            }}\
        ]\
        }}\
        "
        );
        let object: TaskRepositoryForSerialization = serde_json::from_str(&content).unwrap();
        let repo = TaskRepository::from_serialization(object);

        //Can't assert_eq because repo because of dates
        assert_eq!(repo.tasks.len(), expected.len());
        for (key, value) in repo.tasks.iter() {
            assert_eq!(value.id, expected[key].id);
            assert_eq!(value.description, expected[key].description);
            assert_eq!(value.status, expected[key].status);
        }
    }
}

